# Keyword for both types and integrals for parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

If I have a trait that detects a specialisation (i.e. a templated type):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_specialisation : std::false_type {
};

template <template <typename...> class U, typename... Args>
struct is_specialisation<U<Args...>> : std::true_type {
};
```

This works as expected:

```
traits::is_specialisation<std::vector<int>>::value;              // True
traits::is_specialisation<std::string_view>::value;              // True
traits::is_specialisation<std::tuple<char, int, double>>::value; // True
traits::is_specialisation<float>::value;                         // False
```

Except when one of the parameter pack types is actually a value:

```
traits::is_specialisation<std::array<char, 4>>::value;  // False
```

This is because the `template <typename...> class U` declaration is specifically for *types*, if I switched it to `template <auto...> class U` it would accept all values - but is there a way of declaring such it can take a mixture of types *and* values?

Comment: You can follow [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1985r1.pdf).